# How to use multithreading to write downloaded data in one file in a mulithread download application

Tags: multithreading, debian, lazarus, file-writing, idhttp

I want to make a multithread download using Idhttp (indy), so I have a principal thread that starts secondary threads, each secondary thread creates a file: "fileThreadNB" that is supposed to contain downloaded data, then this secondary thread downloads a part of the file on the server using idhttp.request.range and it writes downloaded data in fileThreadNB , then all these files (files created by secondary threads) are copied in one file to get the same file on the server, but the copy here takes a lot of time especially when the file on the server has a big size, so is there any other way that allows threads to write data in the same file, to be clearer; thread 0: downloads from position 0 to m, writes in fileX from position 0 to m .. thread n:downloads from position j to filesize-1, writes in fileX from position j to filesize-1. 
Note: threads must write data in hard drive, so I can resume download later if something bad occurs.
I tried this code instead:

```
procedure   TSecondaryThread.Execute;
begin
HTTP.Request.Range := Format('%d-%d',[BeginPos ,BeginPos +BlockSize -1]);
File.Position:=BeginPos;
HTTP.Get(url,File); 
end;
```

BlockSize is the same for all threads, BeginPos changes from thread to other, the too variables are initialised in TSecondaryThread.Create.
NB:

- when I try use one secondary thread, the file is well downloaded, but when I use more I get this error:External SIGSEGV, and the size of the downloaded file is bigger than the file on the server's size.
- File is a global variable.
  i guess that the problem is  due to:`File.Position:=BeginPos;`but I don't know how to fix it, I would be grateful if someone helps me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the filesize you can create a empty fike with the allocation already configured to that size, then just take care to write for each thread to the right range. There should be no concurrence issues.

Comment: You cant share as it is a gobal varialble btw threads without being aware of race conditions. In the case presented each thread should use a File instance belonging to the thread.